# How to manage the roles fields in drupal views?

Tags: php, drupal

I want to manage the roles for search,add,edit,delete in other role login not in  administrator login and also how to add the fields(role name,role id,role edit link) in views.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can change role permissions as follow:

1. Loging as administrator.
2. Find People->Permissions->Roles (www.example.com/admin/people/permissions/roles).
3. On this page you can find "authenticated user" (login user).
4. By clicking "edit permissions" link you can manage roles permissions.

In Drupal there by default view is present for user listing and in that view this information(role name, edit link) is already present, You can find that view on "People" top Menu (www.example.com/admin/people)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But i want to give the roles management option into another role person for own theme. so i need to create a views for roles(search/edit/delete/add). this case i can't able to added the role id,name,edit link in views.

Comment: Then I would suggest you,  create custom view as per your requirements or you can search for similar kind of module if it is there

Comment: yes i have searched for module but similar kind of module not available and also i checked the views field for role this is also not available, only available for user (edilt link)  fields. Please advice if you have any idea

Comment: then you need to create your own module in drupal and in that you can fetch records and updates records of respective fields/tables